# mysql2 gem installation error on centOS 6.5 deploying

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, mysql2

Basically I have a remote server running CentOS 6.5 and now running Mysql 5.6, but when I try to deploy my rails app via Capistrano I'm getting the following error message:

```
LoadError: /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18: version `libmysqlclient_16' not found (required by /.../mysql2-0.3.17/mysql2/mysql2.so)
```

Any ideas on what that might be?

Here are some additional information:

This is the ldconfig -p output

```
libmysqlclient_r.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.16
libmysqlclient_r.so.15 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.15
libmysqlclient_r.so.14 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.14
libmysqlclient_r.so.12 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.12
libmysqlclient.so.18 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18
libmysqlclient.so.18 (libc6) => /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18
libmysqlclient.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16
libmysqlclient.so.15 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.15
libmysqlclient.so.14 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.14
libmysqlclient.so.12 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.12
libmysqlclient.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so
```

and these are the mysql packages I have installed

mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch
mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.i686
mysql-community-libs-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-server-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-common-5.6.22-2.el6.i686
mysql-community-common-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-devel-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-5.6.22-2.el6.i686

Also I'm running a Rails 4.0.8 app with Capistrano 3.3.5 and my server is set up with Apache + Phusion Passenger

If anybody knows any sort of issue regarding that, will appreciate your help!

Thanks in advance for any incoming help!

EDIT
database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: dbname_development
  pool: 5
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: dbname_test
  pool: 5
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: dbname_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
```

Comment: try installing the mysql development libs:  `sudo yum install mysql-devel` EDIT: Nvm, looks like you already have them

Comment: If it is a empty DB, I might try wiping and reinstalling MySQL on the server.

Comment: I have reinstalled the MySQL packages quite a few times, testing other versions, but it's not really possible to do it again, as I have huge loads of data to keep backing up from several other apps. I read somewhere that it could be a symlink problem to the lib, but as I see it seems it's there, shown on my ldconfig output.

Comment: have you tried explicitly pointing to the mysql installation when installing the gem?  What happens if you run:  `gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql`  ** Note, you might have to change dir path

Comment: Also, just curiosity sake, what is your production database.yml config (with creds abstracted obviously)

Comment: I edited the question with further abstracted information about database.yml, and I'm at the moment trying mysql gem instead of mysql2, which where I come to a point where it doesn't find my database. Pretty new to deploying on manually configured servers, so been kinda hard.

Comment: and for the other question: Cannot find include dir(s) /usr/bin/mysql/include
when I try to install using mysql path

Comment: I guess I should have asked this before, does the Gem actually install?  Is this error actually occurring at runtime?

Comment: Well, I can install it succesfully on remote, the errors appear on deploy.

Comment: It seems they have something to do with the database creation, as this is a fresh app.